# Show static value in best_in_place rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, best-in-place

My code is

```
<%= best_in_place user.user_detail, :unit_number, path: update_unit_number_user_path(user) %>
```

It works fine but I want if unit_number is 0 then it shows "-" . How I do this?

Comment: `unit_number` is an attribute of `user` ?

Comment: yes........................

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= user.unit_number == 0 ? "-" : (best_in_place user.user_detail, :unit_number, path: update_unit_number_user_path(user)) %>
```